# "Go-first" dice for $N$ players

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, dice

I'm interested in sets of dice that can be used to determine who "goes first" (hence the name) in an $N$-player game; more generally, I want to determine a complete ordering of the players with a single roll of the dice, and have this ordering be random.  Specifically, then, what's needed is an assignment of the labels $\{1,2,...,Nm\}$ to the faces of $N$ different $m$-sided dice, such that:

1. No two faces share a label (so no ties can occur).
2. When a face is chosen at random on each die, the rank-ordering of the dice based on the chosen faces is uniformly random across all permutations (so the rolls are fair).

For instance, if $N=2$ and $m=2$ (two coins, basically), then you can label the coins $\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.  A solution for $N=4$ and $m=12$ is sold [here](http://www.ericharshbarger.org/dice/#gofirst_4d12).  For what values of $N$ and $m$ are there solutions?

A simple constraint on the minimum value of $m$ comes from the fact that we are choosing one of $N!$ possibilities on the basis of $m^N$ equiprobable rolls; certainly the former must divide the latter.  So for $N=2,3,4,5,6,\dots$, necessarily $m \ge 2, 6, 6, 30, 30, \dots$.  Is this minimum value always achievable?

Comment: I was just about to post the link to the Harshbarger dice when I saw that you had noted that in your question!  For clarification, do you want your dice set to also have the property that the winner is equiprobable for sets of $n$ dice, $2\leq n\lt N$?  (In other words, do you want a set that will work for any number of players up to $N$, or just a set that works for $N$ players exactly?)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  If you have a version that works for $N$, doesn't it work for any less?  Just ignore the players that aren't there in the order.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ahh, of course!  The 'works for any $n\leq N$' thing was played up on the linked page so I thought it would be an extra constraint, but thinking about it it's just a projection operation on your permutation set, so it keeps equiprobability...

Comment: The case $N=4, m=6$ ought to be within reach; there are $24!/(4!\cdot(6!)^4)\approx 96 \text{billion}$ possible assignments of numbers to dice, with each assignment requiring the $6^4=1296$ different outcomes to be checked, and the projection condition (that any subset of dice also be fair) provides an early-out that should allow a large number of assignments to be automatically culled (e.g., if we find that every face of die $B$ is greater than each face of die $A$, we don't need to distribute the remaining numbers among dice $C$ and $D$)

Comment: In fact, you should be able to use the fairness condition to bound the search space even more: first of all, find out which of the $\binom{12}{6}$ different 2-die assignments are fair, then for each of the $\binom{24}{12}$ ways of assigning the 24 numbers to two pairs of dice, iterate over all of the fair assignments of the first twelve numbers to $A$ and $B$, and all the fair assignments of the other twelve numbers to $C$ and $D$, testing just those combinations for global fairness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the N=4 case, m=6 is *not* sufficient. I exhaustively checked all possible 4d6 configurations and came up empty handed. That is why the GoFirst dice on my website are 4d12 (12-sided). I do not yet know if m=30 is sufficient for N=5 (much less N=6).

Geometrically, a 60-sided fair polyhedron exists and is aesthetically pleasing (q.v. Pentakis Dodecahedron) if that is what is needed. But trying to find a 5d30 is proving more than a typical computer can handle, much less a 5d60.

Comment: Thanks!  You're the de facto expert on the subject, so I appreciate your weighing in.

Answer (score 0):

What constraints are there on $m$, the number of sides of the dice?  Once $N$ hits $7$ you need $7$ to divide $m$ and there are no regular polyhedra that can do that.  If all the dice are the same, you need $m$ to be a multiple of $210$ if $N \ge 7$.  Maybe it is better to use dice of different sizes.  There are [14 sided polyhedra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetradecahedron.html) that look close to spherical.  The truncated cube and truncated octahedron should be able to have the dimensions chosen to be fair.  Then for $N=7$, roll $d14, d20, 2d6$ to get $10080$ possibilities.  If the dice are colored or otherwise distinguishable, all the $m_1m_2 \ldots m_n$ rolls are distinguishable, so if $N! | m_1m_2 \ldots m_n$ you can certainly do what you want.

Comment: I think the idea is to speak about abstract dice - that is, to have $N$ (multi)sets of $m$ elements, rather than specifically physically-realizeable dice.  And I'm not sure your last statement follows; you can certainly assign permutations of players to all of the dice results, but that doesn't mean that you can do it in a way that respects the natural order of the numbers on the dice (which is the point of the idea).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  You are right.  I had missed respecting the natural order.  Even more it looks very hard for $N \ge 7$

Comment: Apart from the nice regular (m=4,6,8,12,20) and Archimedean (m=24,30,48,60,96,120) polyhedra, there are several infinite families of fair shapes, such as the bipyramid (traditional for m=16), the trapezohedron (traditional for m=10), the prism and the antiprism (usually with added endcaps), which allow realization of practical dice for any m.

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the restriction that dice must have equal numbers of faces, then for $N\!=3$, we have (at least) the following two possibilities, with one $6$-sided, one $3$-sided and one $4$-sided dice (a total of $13$ faces):
$$1,3,7,8,11,12\qquad2,9,10\qquad4,5,6,13$$
$$1,3,8,9,10,11\qquad2,7,12\qquad4,5,6,13$$
Since there is no need for faces on any single dice to be distinct, these are equivalent to:
$$1,3,5,5,7,7\qquad2,6,6\qquad4,4,4,8$$
$$1,3,6,6,6,6\qquad2,5,7\qquad4,4,4,8$$
respectively.

It seems likely that there are also solutions for $N\!=4$ with fewer (perhaps a lot fewer) than a total of $48$ faces.

Comment: Good point!  There are, it turns out, three fair possibilities for $2-4-6$ dice, twelve for $3-4-6$, four for $4-4-6$, two for $4-5-6$, thirty-five for $4-6-6$, sixteen for $5-6-6$, and eleven for $6-6-6$.  None of these can be extended to $N=4$, though.